# Migration tool Error: Picklist value: not found

Tags: migration-tool

I am having a lot of problem like this one trying to deploy to my sandbox

1. objects/Case.object (Case.Support Process) -- Error: Picklist value: Value 1 not found (line 61, column 24)

The portion of the Case.object referencing that look like this.

```
<businessProcesses>
    <fullName>Support Process</fullName>
    <description>Support Process</description>
    <isActive>true</isActive>
    <values>
        <fullName>Open</fullName>
        <default>true</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>Close</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>Value 1</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
    ...
</businessProcesses>
```

I have tried with and without CustomField members and BusinessProcess members in the package.xml without sucess always with those same errors.

Could anyone help me and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you check the picklist have correct values, also record type?